# failure to delivere result code in onActivityResult in case of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

having result code problem in case of Fragment when trying to perform Action_pick from gallery , and getting result code null pointer exception. Please can anyone solve out this....
Here is some part of code...

```
con_imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {               
             Intent MYintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

             startActivityForResult(MYintent, 1);                
        }
    });
```

and LogCat msg:

```
06-18 03:13:36.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {org.sipdroid.sipua/org.sipdroid.sipua.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 03:13:36.610: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3346)
```

This code was working perfectly in Activity bot not working in Fragment.
Do anyone have any Solution...plz

Comment: you need to have onactivity result in both activity and fragment

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can do

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(MYintent, 1);
```

and handle the result in `Activity`

or you can leave the code as is and override your fragment's `onActivityResult`